# Converting a datetime into a string and back again

Tags: python, datetime, deserialization

I have a `datetime` that I save to a file like this:

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
f.write(str(time1))
```

Now when I read it I realize `time` is a string. I've tried different ways to convert it but with no luck so far.

```
time = line[x:x+26]
```

How can I convert a string representation of a `datetime` back into a `datetime` object?

Comment: I edited your question to be more specific about what your question was. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, you need to figure out the format of the date in your file and use the [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method, e.g.

```
# substitute your format
# the one below is likely to be what's saved by str(datetime)
previousTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[x:x+26], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

(You'd better use `dt.strftime(...)` than `str(dt)` though)

Then subtract the datetime objects to get a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

```
delta = datetime.datetime.now() - previousTime
```

Answer (score 12):

### It's a little simpler in python 3.7+

**To string:**

```
import datetime

my_date_string = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
```

**From string:**

```
my_date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(my_date_string)
```

Comment: this is the easiest but it looses part of the tx information. It retains the actual hour though. not sure if that matters for daylight savings time or not. For example 
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 12, 37, 54, 303764, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
becomes 
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 12, 37, 54, 303764, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))

Answer (score 11):

Try using `dateutil`. It has a parse that will attempt to convert your string back into a `datetime` object.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> strtime = str(datetime.now())
>>> strtime
'2012-11-13 17:02:22.395000'
>>> parser.parse(strtime)
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 13, 17, 2, 22, 395000)
```

You can then subtract one `datetime` from another and get a `timedelta` object detailing the difference in time.

Comment: When I tried from dateutil import parser in py 2.7 that module didn't exist.  are there any py 2.7 options?

Answer (score 0):

To convert python date time object to string,

```
from datetime import datetime
datatime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
```

To convert python string to datetime object,

```
 from datetime import datetime
 dt_str = datatime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
 datetime.strptime(dt_str,'%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
```

Happy coding..

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
var x = DateTime.parse(time1);
```

Where `x` is your required DateTime object

Comment: Actually in Python a variable isn't declared with var, this would give you a SyntaxError.